# How to run multiple query in single query

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know what kind of title i need to use for this question anyone can help me to choose a title.

Anyway My question is
I need to run this query.

```
SELECT key_features,about_course FROM `page_sections` WHERE page_id=15 AND country_id=241 AND  state_id=291 AND city_id=1277;
```

If no record found. Then i need to run same query with city_id=0

```
SELECT key_features,about_course  FROM `page_sections` WHERE page_id=15 AND country_id=241 AND  state_id=291 AND city_id=0;
```

If no record found. Then i need to run same query with state_id=0 && city_id=0

```
SELECT key_features,about_course  FROM `page_sections` WHERE page_id=15 AND country_id=241 AND  state_id=0 AND city_id=0;
```

If no record found. Then i need to run same query with country_id=0 and state_id=0 && city_id=0

```
SELECT key_features,about_course  FROM `page_sections` WHERE page_id=15 AND country_id=0 AND  state_id=0 AND city_id=0;
```

Now there is any better way to run all this query from top to down and get only one row.

I don't want to use neatened if else...

- If first query work no need to run second
- else if Second query work no need to run third
- else if third query work no need to run fouth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simple approach would be to always select the field with the given id, or zero and then order and limit the result.

```
SELECT key_features,about_course
FROM `page_sections` 
WHERE page_id=15 
    AND (country_id=241 OR country_id=0)
    AND (state_id=291 OR state_id=0)
    AND (city_id=1277 OR city_id=0)
ORDER BY country_id DESC, state_id DESC, city_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  If you want one row, how about this:

```
SELECT key_features, about_course
FROM `page_sections`
WHERE page_id = 15 AND country_id = 241 AND state_id = 291 AND city_id = 1277
UNION ALL
SELECT key_features, about_course
FROM `page_sections`
WHERE page_id = 15 AND country_id = 241 AND state_id = 291 AND city_id = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT key_features, about_course
FROM `page_sections`
WHERE page_id = 15 AND country_id = 241 AND state_id = 0 AND city_id = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT key_features, about_course
FROM `page_sections`
WHERE page_id = 15 AND country_id = 0 AND state_id = 0 AND city_id = 0
ORDER BY country_id DESC, state_id DESC city_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

(This assumes that the ids are all non-negative, which seems like a reasonable assumption.)

The reason I am using `UNION ALL` instead of `OR` is so the subqueries can all take advantage of an index on `page_sections(page_id, country_id, state_id, city_id)`.  Using `OR` would probably preclude the use of an index.

Assuming that there is only one (or a handful of matches) for each condition, this will be a little slower than any of your original queries.  However, it will probably be faster than going back-and-forth to the database multiple times.

EDIT:

Silly me.  In MySQL, this is the best way to write the query:

```
SELECT key_features, about_course
FROM `page_sections`
WHERE (page_id, country_id, state_id, city_id) IN
       ( (15, 241, 291, 1277),
         (15, 241, 291, 0),
         (15, 241, 0, 0),
         (15, 0, 0, 0)
       )
ORDER BY country_id DESC, state_id DESC city_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
SELECT 
  key_features,
  about_course 
FROM 
  page_sections 
WHERE 
  page_id = 15
ORDER BY 
  city_id DESC,
  state_id DESC,
  country_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

because of the `LIMIT 1` you will only get one row. The trick is the ordering. I assume zero is the lowest number in the `country_id`, `state_id` and `city_id` fields, so anything higher should show up first in the results.

EDIT: I removed the selection of the specific `country_id`, `state_id` and `city_id` fields as you asked.

Comment: I think your this ans is best   -> SELECT 
 *
FROM 
  page_sections 
WHERE 
  page_id = 17
ORDER BY 
  city_id DESC,
  state_id DESC,
  country_id DESC
LIMIT 1;

Comment: No need to pass country city state

Comment: Yes, I was thinking along those lines, but wasn't sure it would work on your dataset.

Comment: change your ans

Comment: @daulat are you sure, this it what you asked for? what if, there are entries with (page_id=15, country_id=242) and (page_id=15, country_id=241) and you want the query your example. The Code above would return the entry with country_id=242 instead of country_id=241

Comment: @Philipp: Exactly, I had the correct selection in the conditions, but clearly daulat can do without. I assume that city, state and country are locked to certain pages.